# Combinación de números y letras en JComboBox

Tags: java, mysql, jframe

En un *JFrame* tengo el diseño para imprimir el formato con la información de la base de datos. Tengo un *ComboBox* con el que se selecciona la "operación" y conforme a esa selección se llenan todos los campos correspondientes, me muestra bien cuando selecciono en el *ComboBox* un ítem numérico, el problema surge cuando tiene una letra, por ejemplo:

> No. operación: 27.2

La muestra de forma correcta.

> No. operación: 27.A

Marca error que es el siguiente:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'A' at line 1
>
> at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
>     ...

En un método lleno el *ComboBox* que es el siguiente:

```
public void combo() {

 try {

  stat1 = cn.prepareCall("SELECT DISTINCT noOperacion FROM dibujos");

  resultado = stat1.executeQuery();
        if (resultado != null) {
            DefaultComboBoxModel modeloNoOperacion = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
            while (resultado.next()) {
                modeloNoOperacion.addElement(resultado.getString("noOperacion"));
            }
            comboOperaciones.setModel(modeloNoOperacion);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

... y en el método mostrar lleno todos los componentes con lo seleccionado en el *ComboBox*.

Mis sentencias para los componentes son:

```
String sql = "SELECT referencia, noParte, cantidad, nombreNoParte, sufijo1, sufijo2, sufijo3, sufijo4, sufijo5 FROM dibujos WHERE noOperacion=" + comboOperaciones.getSelectedItem();

String sql1 = "SELECT noOperacion, notas, añoModelo, descripcionOperacion, departamento, nota FROM dibujos WHERE noOperacion=" + comboOperaciones.getSelectedItem();

String sql2 = "SELECT dibujos1, dibujos2 FROM dibujos WHERE noOperacion=" + comboOperaciones.getSelectedItem();
```

¿Me podrían dar una idea de cómo solucionar este problema? y que me muestre ¿Cuándo se tiene una letra en el campo de `noOperacion`?

Comment: ya probaste la consulta con los dos valores antes de pegarla al codigo?
Que tipo de dato es ''noOperacion''?
El erro dice ser de Syntaxis.

Comment: Lo acabo de hacer y sí, el error es de Sintaxis porque cuando hago la consulta me arroja esto:

`SELECT noOperacion, notas, añoModelo, descripcionOperacion, departamento, nota FROM dibujos WHERE noOperacion=27.A LIMIT 0, 30`

noOperacion es de tipo varchar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La sintaxis es incorrecta porque noOperación se trata de un varchar por lo tanto el valor va entre comillas simples.

Deberias construir tu consulta de esta manera:

```
String sql1 = "SELECT noOperacion, notas, añoModelo, descripcionOperacion, departamento, nota FROM dibujos WHERE noOperacion= '" + comboOperaciones.getSelectedItem(); + "'"
```

Comment: Completamente cierto, hasta ahorita vengo reaccionando, ahora sí funciona sin problema, muchas gracias.

Comment: De nada. Para valores numéricos funcionaba porque sql admite tanto valores con comillas simples como sin. Si te sirvio te agradezco que califiques positivamente la respuesta :)